# Can statistical inference be performed in a multi-armed bandit scenario?

Tags: inference, multiarmed-bandit

[Statistical inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference) is the process of using data analysis to deduce properties of an underlying probability distribution. [Multi-armed bandit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) is a technique to try different options and sample more often from options that are successful. Multi-armed bandits are often contrasted with A/B testing which gets the same, fixed number of samples from each option.

Is there any reason that statistical inference can not performed on the data from a multi-armed bandits experiment?

Comment: I suppose inference could be performed post facto, but the problem lies in the fact that bandit problems are intended to sample more heavily from successful variants.  Smaller samples from less successful variants leads to a loss of precision, hence wider confidence intervals.  Consequently, we learn a lot less about unsuccessful variants and more about successful variants.